# Select query inside a select query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running the following query on the table with multiple records having different quantity fields but the same id.

```
SELECT MIN( quantity ) 
  FROM ( SELECT * 
           FROM `ready_for_delivery` 
          WHERE joborderid LIKE 00065 
          ORDER BY joborderid DESC ) a 
 GROUP BY quantity
```

It is returning all the values and not the minimum value. Any ideas why? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Yes, but rather than an explanation, wouldn't you prefer a solution?

Comment: I would be happy to have a solution

Comment: With that in mind, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How is phpMyAdmin related to the query?

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a subquery doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
SELECT MIN( quantity ) as 'Min' FROM ( SELECT * FROM `ready_for_delivery` WHERE joborderid LIKE 00065 ORDER BY joborderid DESC )a
```

If you are only after a single value, you should not be using a `group by`.

**Definition for Group by:**

A `GROUP BY` clause works on the rows returned by a query by summarizing identical rows into a single/distinct group and returns a single row with the summary for each group, by using appropriate Aggregate function in the 
SELECT list, like

- COUNT()
- SUM()
- MIN()
- MAX()
- AVG().